# MySQL tagging system - top keywords per month

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, tagging

I have a "Has-many-through" table `keyword_sentence` which contains links from the sentences to the keywords.

```
TABLE `keyword_sentence` {
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sentence_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sentence_id` (`sentence_id`),
  KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`)
)
```

**How do I get the top 5 keywords per week?**

I would like to see which `keyword_id`'s are being used each week so I can watch for trending items. I currently have the following query which isn't quite working.

```
SELECT ks.keyword_id
FROM
  keyword_sentence ks
WHERE ks.keyword_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ks2.keyword_id FROM keyword_sentence ks WHERE
  from_unixtime(ks.created) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
  AND 
  from_unixtime(ks.created) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: You are asking about week, but your query is about months.  Which are you interested in?  How is your query not working?

Comment: I want to see the top 5 keywords per week in the month range given. So if it was last month there should be 20 records max (4 weeks * 5 keywords = 20 results).

Comment: Can you use a database stored procedure and cursor over the four weeks    selecting the top keyword of each week into a temp table and at the end select everything from that temp table.

Comment: "top keywords per month" "top 5 keywords per week" WHICH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, @rowNo := if(@pv = week, @rowNo+1, 1) as rNo, @pv := week
    FROM (
        SELECT keyword_id, COUNT(*), YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) AS week
        FROM keyword_sentence
        WHERE 
            FROM_UNIXTIME(created) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
        AND
            FROM_UNIXTIME(created) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY week, keyword_id
        ORDER BY week, COUNT(*) DESC
    ) temp
    JOIN (
        SELECT @rowNo := 0, @pv := 0
    ) tempValue
) tmp
WHERE
    tmp.rNo < 6
```

### **[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcfd0e/7)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this queryies ??

```
SELECT DISTINCT(keyword_id) FROM tmp WHERE created BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' LIMIT 0, 20;
```

OR without DISTINCT

```
SELECT keyword_id FROM tmp WHERE created BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Then, if you have five or more per week them appeared, 
I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT ks.keyword_id, count(*)
FROM keyword_sentence ks
WHERE from_unixtime(ks.created) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND 
      from_unixtime(ks.created) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
group by ks.keyword_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
limit 5;
```

Comment: That would only fetch the top five keywords in the last month. I want the top five keywords for each week in the month. I know a subquery is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a basic count, grouped by keyword and week:-

```
SELECT keyword_id, WEEK(ks.created) AS theWeek, COUNT(*)
FROM keyword_sentence 
WHERE from_unixtime(created) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
AND from_unixtime(created) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY keyword_id, theWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear if you are looking for month or week, so i did it for MONTH.
Here is the code:

```
SELECT keyword_id, MONTH(from_unixtime(created)) AS theMonth, COUNT(*) As keywordCount
FROM keyword_sentence 
WHERE from_unixtime(created) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
AND from_unixtime(created) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY keyword_id, theMonth
ORDER BY keywordCount DESC
```

And the Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76c5d/8/0